# Logstash: Xml filter: Unable to get parent and child attributes in one row

Tags: xml, logstash, kibana

I am new to Kibana, logstash. I am trying push xml (generated as output of nunit) in logstash. I want to have the xml elements attributes, its Parents attributes and child attributes in the same row in Kibana.
However, i can get only the xml elements attribute. Parent and child attributes are not generated in the same row.

### Below is the XML file Iam using:

```
<test-suite type="TestFixture" name="bootAPIs" executed="True" result="Failure" success="False" time="12.811" asserts="0">
  <results>
    <test-case name="NunitBETests.bootAPIs.GetSeriescount" executed="True" result="Success" success="True" time="0.944" asserts="0">
      <reason name="NeededforBooting">
        <message />
      </reason>
    </test-case>
    <test-case name="NunitBETests.bootAPIs.GetSeriescount" executed="True" result="Success" success="True" time="0.910" asserts="0">
      <reason>
        <message />
      </reason>
    </test-case>
    <test-case name="NunitBETests.bootAPIs.GetToken" executed="True" result="Success" success="True" time="0.462" asserts="0">
     <reason>
        <message />
      </reason>
   </test-case>
  </results>
</test-suite>
```

---

### Below is Logstash Config File I am using:

```
input { stdin { } }
filter {
xml {
store_xml => false
source => "message"
xpath =>
[
"//test-case/@name", "testcase",
"//test-case/@result", "res",
"//test-case/../../@name", "suitename",
"//test-case/reason/@name","reasonattr",
"//test-case/@time", "timetest"
]
}

date {
match => [ "date" , "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss" ]
timezone => "Europe/Amsterdam"
}

}

output {

elasticsearch {
action => "index"
index => "xml12"
hosts => ["localhost:9200"]

}

stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

---

Result:
I am getting this output:

```
{
"message" => " <test-case name="NunitBETests.bootAPIs.GetSeriescount" executed="True" result="Success" success="True" time="0.462" asserts="0">\r",
"testcase" => [
[0] "NunitBETests.bootAPIs.GetSeriescount"
],
"res" => [
[0] "Success"
],

      "host" => "DESKTOP-PC8JBMK"
}
```

However I am want to capture parent attribute of "testcase" node (that is "suitename") and child attribute of "testcase" xmlnode (that is "reasonattr") in same row.
Something like below is what i want to have:

```
{
"message" => " <test-case name="NunitBETests.bootAPIs.GetSeriescount" executed="True" result="Success" success="True" time="0.462" asserts="0">\r",
"testcase" => [
[0] "NunitBETests.bootAPIs.GetSeriescount"
],
"res" => [
[0] "Success"
],
"suitename" => [
[0] "bootAPIs"
],
"reasonattr" => [
[0] "NeededforBooting"
],

"@timestamp" => 2018-01-09T05:53:07.678Z,
  "@version" => "1",
  "timetest" => [
    [0] "0.462"
],
      "host" => "DESKTOP-PC8JBMK"
}
```

Please let me know what I am missing here.

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I was not passing the xml correctly as stdin. After passing it as a single unit without any newline, it got parsed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Pasting here the complete details, just in case that it may assit some one else tooo...

Problem statement:
Below xml is an output generate out of Nunit . I need to collect attributes of all test-case nodes
along with the attributes of its Parent and child nodes in a single event per testcase so that every event generated by Logstash has testcase name, testsuite name(parent node) and Failure message (child node) for all testcases in the xml.

XMl below:

```
<test-suite type="Assembly" name="C:\vinayDoNotDelete\ComponentTestallFiles\Softwares\OtherCsharpSOlutionsunitBETests\bin\Debugunitbetests.exe" executed="True" result="Failure" success="False" time="18.987" asserts="0">
  <results>
    <test-suite type="Namespace" name="NunitBETests" executed="True" result="Failure" success="False" time="18.978" asserts="0">
      <results>
        <test-suite type="TestFixture" name="bootAPIs" executed="True" result="Failure" success="False" time="12.811" asserts="0">
          <results>
            <test-case name="NunitBETests.bootAPIs.GetMOvieFilter" executed="True" result="Failure" success="False" time="1.582" asserts="0">
              <failure>
                ycaddztg
                <message>
                  <![CDATA[Either there are no linear channels or response is incorrect,
 REQUEST is : {"initObj":{"Locale":{"LocaleLanguage":"","LocaleCountry":"","LocaleDevice":"","LocaleUserState":"Unknown"},"Platform":"ConnectedTV","SiteGuid":"958863","DomainID":543335,"UDID":"616439088037","ApiUser":"tvpapi_185si","ApiPass":"A2d4G6","Token":""},"ChannelID":"3407167","picSize":"302x170","pageSize":0,"pageIndex":0,"orderBy":"None","tagsMetas":[],"cutWith":"AND"}
 RESPONSE is : []]]>
                </message>
                <stack-trace>
                  <![CDATA[at NunitBETests.bootAPIs.GetMOvieFilter() in c:\vinayDoNotDelete\ComponentTestallFiles\Softwares\OtherCsharpSOlutionsunitBETests\bootAPIs.cs:line 183
]]>
                </stack-trace>
              </failure>
            </test-case>

            <test-case name="NunitBETests.bootAPIs.GetSubscriptions" executed="True" result="Success" success="True" time="0.921" asserts="0">
              <reason>
                <message />
              </reason>
            </test-case>
            kvlrw
            <test-case name="NunitBETests.bootAPIs.GetProgram" executed="True" result="Success" success="True" time="1.574" asserts="0">
              <reason>
                <message />
              </reason>
            </test-case>

            <test-case name="NunitBETests.bootAPIs.GetSchedule" executed="True" result="Success" success="True" time="1.787" asserts="0">
              <reason>
                dxgarfj
                <message />
              </reason>
            </test-case>
            <test-case name="NunitBETests.bootAPIs.GetGuid" executed="True" result="Success" success="True" time="0.903" asserts="0">
              <reason>
                <message />
              </reason>
            </test-case>
            <test-case name="NunitBETests.bootAPIs.GetAllVeggies" executed="True" result="Success" success="True" time="0.944" asserts="0">
              <reason>
                <message />
              </reason>
            </test-case>
            <test-case name="NunitBETests.bootAPIs.GetAllNoNVegies" executed="True" result="Success" success="True" time="0.910" asserts="0">
              <reason>
                <message />
              </reason>
            </test-case>
            <test-case name="NunitBETests.bootAPIs.Refresh" executed="True" result="Success" success="True" time="0.462" asserts="0">
              <reason>
                <message />
              </reason>
            </test-case>
          </results>
        </test-suite>
        <test-suite type="TestFixture" name="epgAPIs" executed="True" result="Failure" success="False" time="3.392" asserts="0">
          <results>
            <test-case name="NunitBETests.epgAPIs.GetMOvieFilter" executed="True" result="Failure" success="False" time="0.912" asserts="0">
              <failure>
                <message>
                  <![CDATA[Either there are no series recordings or response incorrect, response is : []]]>
                </message>
                kuxxlc
                <stack-trace>
                  <![CDATA[at NunitBETests.epgAPIs.GetMOvieFilter() in c:\vinayDoNotDelete\ComponentTestallFiles\Softwares\OtherCsharpSOlutionsunitBETests\epgAPIs.cs:line 43
]]>
                </stack-trace>
              </failure>
            </test-case>
            <test-case name="NunitBETests.epgAPIs.GetProgram" executed="True" result="Success" success="True" time="1.565" asserts="0">
              <reason>
                <message />
              </reason>
            </test-case>
            jlsb
            <test-case name="NunitBETests.epgAPIs.GetData" executed="True" result="Success" success="True" time="0.908" asserts="0">
              <reason>
                <message />
              </reason>
            </test-case>
          </results>
        </test-suite>
        <test-suite type="TestFixture" name="recordingsAPIs" executed="True" result="Success" success="True" time="2.759" asserts="0">
          <results>
            <test-case name="NunitBETests.recordingsAPIs.GetRecordings" executed="True" result="Success" success="True" time="1.810" asserts="0">
              <reason>
                <message />
              </reason>
            </test-case>
            <test-case name="NunitBETests.recordingsAPIs.GetVeggies" executed="True" result="Success" success="True" time="0.944" asserts="0">
              <reason>
                <message />
              </reason>
            </test-case>
            oagfymbn
          </results>
        </test-suite>
      </results>
    </test-suite>
  </results>
</test-suite>
```

Logtash filter below:

```
input { stdin { }

}
filter {
xml {

store_xml => true
target => "poc"
source => "message"

}
split {
field => "poc[results][0][test-suite][0][results][0][test-suite]"
}

split {
field => "poc[results][0][test-suite][0][results][0][test-suite][results][0][test-case]"
}

date {
match => [ "date" , "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss" ]
timezone => "Europe/Amsterdam"
}

mutate {
add_field => { "number22" => "%{poc[results][0][test-suite][0][results][0][test-suite][name]}" }
add_field => { "name22" => "%{poc[results][0][test-suite][0][results][0][test-suite][results][0][test-case][name]}" }
add_field => { "res22" => "%{poc[results][0][test-suite][0][results][0][test-suite][results][0][test-case][result]}" }
add_field => { "reason22" => "%{poc[results][0][test-suite][0][results][0][test-suite][results][0][test-case][failure][0][message][0]}" }

}

if [reason22] == "%{poc[results][0][test-suite][0][results][0][test-suite][results][0][test-case][failure][0][message][0]}" {
mutate { update => { "reason22" => "" } }
}
}
output {
elasticsearch {
action => "index"
index => "xm64"
hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
}
stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```